# Why are badges hidden in user cards when the account is suspended?

Tags: support, account-suspension, user-card

For suspended users, badges are not shown in their user cards at all. They only show "1" with their avatars and usernames, as if they are new users.  Why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the suspended user was a highly-active user with a lot of badges, the fact that they have only 1 rep but lots of high-value badges makes the fact that the user is suspended extremely obvious. For instance, imagine how this would look:

> [image: 1 rep but lots of badges]

On the other hand, not showing the badges on the user card makes it less obvious, especially to new and anonymous users, that the user is suspended, unless one explicitly clicks to access their user profile or remembers having interacted with the user in the past.