# Suspended users' badge counts show up in edit histories

Tags: bug, badges, revisions-list, account-suspension, user-card

The user card for a suspended user in an edit history page (a page with a URL like site.stackexchange.com/posts/12345/revisions) shows the badge counts for the suspended user, along with 1 reputation. I think the badge counts started showing up recently, and it causes an unexplained asymmetry between the user card for suspended users that shows up underneath answers, which shows 1 rep and 0 badges.

For privacy reasons, I am not posting a screenshot; please let me know if you have trouble re-producing it, and mention how I can provide a screenshot without drawing attention to a particular suspension (since we don't immortalize public suspension records here). Is it okay to just post a link to a question where I observed it?

Here is the way to reproduce it:

1. Identify a question/answer edited by a presently suspended user. This could be done by going to a suspended user's profile and searching in all actions>revisions.
2. Open the edit history.

I just observed this on physics meta, for a user suspended network-wide until 2030, using the latest version of Safari for Mac. I believe I've noticed it in other places too.

The badges *used* to be hidden until the page styling was modified to be responsive. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330786/377214) for why the system removes this information from user cards.

Comment: @Sonic Are you sure about that edit? I don't see any mention of it in https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/1059395 I didn't carefully inspect every single link, but I don't immediately see any headlines that look like they'd include this.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361478/377214. Per that post, the same code was used to render the user card on posts and revision histories, and that same code took care of not only rounding but also removing the badge display for suspended users. Since that change, though, they now use different code.

Comment: No badges show up on narrow screens, so take that into account when reproducing. Also, you don’t have to find an edit by a suspended user, just a post of theirs that has been edited. the badges show up on the initial revision.